# SQL - Auto number columns based on another columns

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I have been trying to solve my problem below with the IF and CASE WHEN statements but I am not getting the result that I need so, I hope you can help me.

Suppose I have this table:

```
Client | address
----------------
John   | add1
John   | add2
Fred   | add1
Amy    | add1
Amy    | add2
Amy    | add3
```

1) How I can set a incremented value in a new column (ID) **for each different client**, to get this result:

```
ID | Client | address
---------------------
1  | John   | add1
1  | John   | add2
2  | Fred   | add1
3  | Amy    | add1
3  | Amy    | add2
4  | Amy    | add3
```

2) How I can set a incremented value in a new column (Site) **for each different client with a different address**, to get this result:

```
ID | Site | Client | address
----------------------------
1  | 1    | John   | add1
1  | 2    | John   | add2
2  | 1    | Fred   | add1
3  | 1    | Amy    | add1
3  | 2    | Amy    | add2
4  | 3    | Amy    | add3
```

Best Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to make JOIN with fake indexed table

```
SET @clientId=0;

SELECT idc.clientId, t.*
FROM `table` as t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT address, @clientId:=@clientId+1 AS clientId
    FROM `table`
    ) as idc
    ON idc.address = t.address
```

And for the part 2 it's the same

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by client) as id,
       row_number() over (partition by client order by address) as site,
       client, address
from t;
```

These are ANSI standard functions, which are available in most databases.

Comment: Gordon, what change should be done to the code if you have to use distinct?

Comment: @ElioFernandes . . . I don't understand your comment.  There is no need to use `distinct`.  Perhaps you should ask another question.